# Split words in Enumeration

Tags: lists, split

When enumerating conjoined words that share a common (the last) part, do you apply the same "splitting-" pattern in English as you would do in German, which is for instance:

> This chapter is about the **lexical-, syntactical- and semantic
>   analysis**.

Or, consider another example:

> The goal is, to detect as many **stress- and emotion conditions** as
>   possible.

In the latter, is is correct to write **"stress-"** or simply **"stress"**?

Comment: Are you asking about the hyphen after the term *lexical* and *syntactical*?

Comment: well, without enumeration, one would need to write: **"This chapter is about lexical analysis, syntactical analysis and semantic analysis"**. I am asking about the correct way, to abbreviate this list in order to use the word **analysis** only once.

Comment: I don't see why you cannot write the same sentence without using hyphens. ..lexical, syntactical and semantic analysis.

Comment: *lexical analysis* are two distinct separate terms, not a split one.

Comment: @Josh61 Yes. I agree with you. As the words *lexical* and *syntactical* exist as single words in their own right there is no need to include a hyphen - just a comma.

Comment: you mean, if the two words are separate ones, there is no need to split them? Ok, interesting, If that's true, then I was using it wrongly in German too :)

Comment: Ok, thank you for the quick reply .. helps me in doing the review of a paper I am currently working on :)